# Como achar o resto da divisão?

Tags: c, matemática

Estou estudando de uma apostila que achei na net, ela pede um exercício, mas não ensinou a fazer ele nas páginas anteriores, eu tentei e não deu certo, agradeço pela ajuda de vocês.

> Faça um programa que leia e armazene em variáveis dois números inteiros quaisquer. Calcular e apresentar
> o resto da divisão de um pelo outro

```
    float num1, num2, media;

    printf("\n digite um valor: ");
    scanf("%f",&num1);
    printf("\n digite outro valor: ");
    scanf("%f",&num2);

    media = num1 % num2;

    printf("\n %f \n", media);
```

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 9):

Na matemática só é possível achar o resto quando pensamos em números inteiros, por isso o tipo não pode ser `float`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1, num2, resto;
    printf("\n digite um valor: ");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("\n digite outro valor: ");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    resto = num1 % num2;
    printf("\n %d \n", resto);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/seFxJx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jliryaum-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/Mod.c).

Use nomes de variáveis significativos. Se está calculando o resto, chame ela de `resto` e não de `media`.

Answer (score 4):

O motivo pelo qual o seu código não funciona já foi abordado, use variáveis do tipo `int` para que a divisão retorne o resto e não um número com casas decimais. Uma outra forma interessante de resolver este problema de resto da divisão é usando apenas a matemática. Este é o processo que fazemos naturalmente em uma conta de divisão com resto, multiplicamos o `resultado` pelo divisor(`num1`) e subtraímos isso do dividendo(`num2`), assim temos o `resto`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1, num2, resultado, resto;
    printf("\n digite um valor: ");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("\n digite outro valor: ");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    resultado = num1 / num2;
    resto = num1 - (resultado * num2);
    printf("\n %d \n", resto);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
int a,b;
printf("Digite o valor do dividendo: ");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("Digite o valor do divisor: ");
scanf("%d",&b);
while(a>=b)
a=a-b;
printf("\nResto: %d",a);
getchar();
}
```

Nesse método, o usuário digita o primeiro valor (dividendo) depois digita o segundo valor (divisor). Os dois valores entram em um laço while cuja principal função é que o valor do primeiro valor (dividendo) saia do laço quando o dividendo seja menor que o divisor.

Exemplo:

Se o usuário digitar 35 para o dividendo e 4 para o divisor, temos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
int a,b;
printf("Digite o valor do dividendo: ");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("Digite o valor do divisor: ");
scanf("%d",&b);
while(a>=b) {
a=a-b;
printf("\nValor do dividendo por enquanto = %d",a); //Linha acrescentada para mostar o laço
}
printf("\nResto: %d",a);
getchar();
}
```

[image: Laço para o cálculo do resto sendo executado]

Comment: Forneça um pouco mais de detalhes em sua resposta!