# Estou em dúvida de como fazer

Tags: c, matemática

Como por módulo em alguma função matemática no C? Tentei algumas coisas básicas mas não funcionou.

Comment: poste seu código ai, ou coisas que você ja tentou e não deu certo, seja mais claro na pergunta...Isso ajuda a obter respostas mais rápidas e precisas.

Comment: O módulo que você fala é o resto da divisão? Seria `5%2` que resultaria em `1`, isso?

Comment: Tem algum problema específico que está tendo em algum código? Poste ele. Se quer só genericamente sobre o uso do operador de módulo, tem uma pergunta de alguns minutos atrás que responde isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88260/problema-em-c-como-achar-o-resto-da-divis%c3%a3o

Comment: Sua pergunta tá meio estranha, recomendo que vc a edite e coloque algo como "Como calcular o resto da divisão em C?" ou "Como utilizar a função modulo em C?" assim ajudará outras pessoas no futuro com a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para calcular o módulo de um número qualquer verifique dois casos sendo o número positivo, o seu código não faz nada, sendo o número negativo torne-o positivo.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int modulo(int num);

main()
{
    printf("%d", modulo(2));
    printf("%d", modulo(-2));
}

int modulo(int num)
{
    int resultado;

    if(num < 0)
        resultado = -num;
    else
        resultado = num;

    return resultado;
}
```

Se a sua dúvida se refere ao uso do operador módulo (`%`) que retorna o resto da divisão pode usar assim.

```
int resto, dividendo, divisor;
resto = dividendo % divisor;
```